# How could I stop spam if my form is using ajax submit method (with no reload)?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form which uses ajax for data submitting. Here is the html:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="content" name="content">
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="button">
</form>
```

and the JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    //Update Message...
    $(".button").click(function() {
        var boxval = $("#content").val();
        var dataString = 'content='+ boxval;

        if(boxval=='')
        {
            alert("Please Enter Some Text");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#flash").show();
            $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle"> <span class="loading">Loading Comment...</span>');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "update_data.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("ol#update").prepend(html);
                    $("ol#update li:first").slideDown("slow");
                    document.getElementById('content').value='';
                    document.getElementById('content').focus();
                    $("#flash").hide();
                }
            });
        } 
        return false;
    });
});
```

It is all working fine, but there is a big problem: I cannot stop spam.
Last time I used spam filters, it was in PHP (I used a hidden input and then checked in the PHP file if it is filled out). But that was totally in PHP, no JS.

So here is my question:
How could I stop spam in this form submission? Also, can I create an `if` statement in the `update_data.php` file?

Comment: First of all, you need to start indenting your code and stop mixing jQuery with plain JavaScript (`document.getElementById('content').value=''; document.getElementById('content').focus();` => `$('#content').val().get(0).focus()`). Besides that, if you create a form that has no valid `action` bots are unlikely to successfully submit it - and for real users with JavaScript enabled you specify the target URL in the $.ajax call anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I you do not like to add Captcha here is a good solution:

First add input that is hidden with css in the form. If the bot submits the form the hidden field will have some value filled by the bot. In normal cases the human will not see it and will be empty. In the case of a bot you will check it and if it has some value you will discard.
Also you need to add input (also hidden with css) with javascript on document ready. If it is browser it will execute the javascript and will insert the input in the form. If it is a bot then the bots do not execute js and there will be no input field generated by js and on the server side you will see that there is no such field and you will discard the request.

So on the server side you will check if the first hidden field has value or the second hidden field does not exist discard the request.

Comment: Even though this is a good solution does not prevent the bot to submit the form. It means the server will have the same number of spam request, the same load since has to check same number of submitted form, so not that big deal. Seems to me a way to put the dust under the carpet, and not clean the floor from the dust :P

Comment: There is no way to prevent the public url to be called. The load will not be the same because after the server will receive the request will validate it and discard it. Because it is public URL everyone can call it (does not need to be by submitting form). By the way the bod does not submit the form but directly use socket to the public URL. So there is no way to prevent the bot for sending a request to a public url, but you can prevent processing data from the bot. The Captcha will not prevent the bot from sending request. The Captcha is also server side validated like the above solution

Comment: Oh well.. token are needed just for this. Generated on the form side, checked on the server side. Without inserting useless js functions.

Answer (score 3):

First fast answer is putting inside the form something that could help you to understand if the user submitting your form is a bot or not.

Captcha for sure, or just a question not easy to answer for a bot.